# How to change ag-grid row group indent?

Tags: css, sass, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to change (increase/decrease) the magnitude of indent (current default is `28px`) for each inner group in my [Tree Data](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/). However, I could not find any configuration options for the same in the documentation. The closest thing I could find was [suppressPadding](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-provided-renderer-group/), which disables padding altogether. I tried using DOM piercing CSS but found that every level has a different CSS class (ex. `ag-row-group-indent-2`), which makes writing a general CSS rule in my container component difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, I'm overriding the style in a loop, which seems to be working

```
// Taken from https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/dist/styles/ag-theme-base/sass/parts/_grid-layout.scss
// support 20 levels here because row group indentation is used for tree data which can be quite deep
@for $i from 1 to 20 {
    .ag-row-group-indent-#{$i} {
        padding-left: $i * 8px;
    }

    .ag-row-level-#{$i} .ag-row-group-leaf-indent {
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `cellStyle` callback that computes the `padding-left` value for each cell based on its current group level.

```js
defaultColDef: {
  cellStyle: (params) => {
    const { level } = params.node;
    const groupCell = params.value === params.node.key;
    const indent = 28; // change this value to your liking

    if (groupCell) {
      return {
        paddingLeft: (level + 1) * indent + "px"
      };
    }
  }
},
```

If you use this approach, remember to suppress the initial css padding value from agGrid or both agGrid and your padding values will add up.

```css
::ng-deep .ag-cell-wrapper.ag-row-group[class*="ag-row-group-indent"],
::ng-deep .ag-cell-wrapper.ag-row-group-leaf-indent[class*="ag-row-group-indent"] {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64374287/how-to-change-ag-grid-row-group-indent]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SCSS and theming, you can change the indent by setting the value of `row-group-indent-size`, like this:

```
:root {
    @include ag-theme-balham(( 
        row-height: 20px,
        cell-horizontal-padding: 8px,
        row-group-indent-size: 18px
    ));
}
```

Reference: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation-variables/